# exclude complete record if related table has a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have `CLAIMMASTER` table like this

```
CLAIMNO
123
456
789
```

and another related table `PROCSTATUS` like this

```
CLAIMNO  PROCCODE
123       111
123       222
456       111
456       222
789       222
```

I want to exclude the records from table1 where proccode in table2 is 111

the result should be

```
CLAIMNO
789
```

I have tried almost everything i can but the closest result i get is like this

```
CLAIMNO   PROCCODE
123       222
456       222
789       222
```

I know this should be easy but i can't figure out the query to do this.
please help.

Here is the query

```
select a.CLAIMNO,b.PROCCODE from dbo.CLAIMMASTER a left join  
dbo.PROCSTATUS b on a.CLAIMNO = b.CLAIMNO
where a.CLAIMNO not in (select b.CLAIMNO where b.PROCCODE  in ('111'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to select claimno then no need to have join.

```
select a.CLAIMNO from dbo.CLAIMMASTER a
where a.CLAIMNO not in 
(select distinct b.CLAIMNO from dbo.PROCSTATUS b where b.PROCCODE = '111')
```

Also if you have claimno repeated in the claimmaster table then you need to use distinct in the select clause.

Comment: Thanks, this works best when i use it in the actual query as the actual query contains lots of unions and joins which causes claim numbers to be repeated when i join the procstatus table in it, this query avoids them. Sorry jobhab but i have to select this as answer although yours and sarslan answer hit the spot too

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.CLAIMNO
from dbo.CLAIMMASTER a 
inner join  dbo.PROCSTATUS b 
on a.CLAIMNO = b.CLAIMNO
where a.CLAIMNO not in 
(select CLAIMNO FROM dbo.PROCSTATUS  where PROCCODE  in ('111'))
```

Comment: thanks both jophab and sarslan, both queries work fine, thanks for the super quick response. I didn't think that just removing the b from b.PROCCODE in ('111') would do the trick. I get the idea why this happened but can you please explain why did it work